# How to center text when you have another div with float

Tags: html, css

I'm getting a little bit confused about how to center vertically text inside div which have two divs inside (first: text, second: button with float)

Is that possible to do it without any multiple lines?
https://jsfiddle.net/jr9yx3kx/

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <span>Information box lorem ipsum</span>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-solid">Why is it not correct?</a>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert {
    padding: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 0.215rem;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
}
.alert a.btn {
  float: right;
}
.btn {
  padding: 0.429rem 0.929rem;
    font-size: 0.858rem;
    border-radius: 0.143rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.57142857;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You can't float inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the usual method for vertical centering, giving the container `position: relative`and the `span` these settings:

```
.alert span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```css
.alert {
  padding: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 0.215rem;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.alert span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.alert a.btn {
  float: right;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.429rem 0.929rem;
  font-size: 0.858rem;
  border-radius: 0.143rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.57142857;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <span>Information box lorem ipsum</span>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-solid">Why is it not correct?</a>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as the selected answer; helps with the search results. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a very nice solution. If the text in the span grows, it eventually overlaps the button. This will probably break in smaller screens. Why not actually putting the text and button in a separate div (as stated by TS but not reflected in his example). Then you can vertically center the button and the text far better I think.

Comment: My solution was made for the existing situation, and there it works well. Re "If the text in the span grows": Then in the first place I wouldn't put it into a span, but into a DIV, since a span is by default in inline element. But that situation wasn't given in the question,

Comment: Hi Johannes, as the span (flow-level element) is here located in a block-level element (the div) it is OK. So, technically there is no need for putting it in a div. But it would be neater to put it in a block-level element, like a P for example, because the content of the span here does not exactly portray itself as content of a flow-level element. The flow-level type of content is more incidentally used, like some bold written words in a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the span to be centered in the gray box and button to be under the text, but floated to the right?

If so, add some CSS for the span:

```
span {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jr9yx3kx/1/